# TFS 2015 Publish attachment to Test Run Summary

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Is there a possibility to add a custom file (e.g. custom Selenium report for all tests) into the body of Run summary itself (Runs -> Run Summary -> Attachments).

Tests are executed using the vNext "Run Functional Tests" task, the unit framework used in tests is a `TestTools.UnitTesting`.

I know that there is a `TestContext.AddTestResult` but it attaches file to a specific test, while I want to use some sort of a summary file for the whole run.

[Test Run Summary in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMMET.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display your custom result in the test run summary or build result summary, seems you will have to write your own extensions. Help link: [Overview of extensions for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)

Base for this  were a lot of examples provided by MS on github:

- [Visual Studio Team Services Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks)
- [Visual Studio Team Services Sample Extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)

To get a first feeling **what places on your TFS Web Portal can be extended/customized** you can download and install this extension  [Contributions Guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide)  from the *Visual Studio Marketplace*.

Comment: So, Attachments section that already exists in test run summary is something that can be affected only from some task?

Comment: Exactly, the original  `.trx` file  in the attachment are generated automatically  when you enable the code coverage. So if you want to add your custom report, you may have to do the customization.